# Header values with commas

Tags: http, http-headers

According to the HTTP specs a header can look like this:

```
Header-Name=value1,value2,value3,...
```

I try to parse the header values and store them as an array:

```
array('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

so far so good. I can just tokenize the string if a comma appears.

**BUT** how should I handle headers like this one:

```
Expires=Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
```

there's a comma but in the one value the header has. Oh that's easy I thought and figuered out the rule: Only separate by commas when there's *no* space before and after the comma. This way both examples get parsed correct.

**BUT** then I came across a header like this:

```
Accept-Encding=gzip, deflate
```

and now? Is this one value `array('gzip, deflate')` or two values `array('gzip', 'deflate')`? For me they are two separate values but then my rule from the above isn't true anymore.

Is there a list which headers are allowed more than once? So I can check against a blacklist to determine if the comma means a value delimiter or not?

Answer (score 8):

Comma concatenation can occur for any header field, even those that aren't designed for it; it's how libraries and intermediaries happen to work.

It is *designed* to be used for header fields that use list syntax (RFC 7230 has all the details: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2. To quote: *A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.*).

Finally, you can't use generic code to tokenize, because the way the comma can occur inside values varies from field to field.

Comment: yep, and some should never use multiple values (like 'Content-length' and 'Host'). Welcome in hell :-)